# Confusing use of 聞く in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> 試験では、ことばを覚えているかどうか**聞く**問題を減らすように言っています。
>   (Scientists) are saying to reduce the problem in exams of whether or not you've memorised a word.

I'm not sure I've translated this correctly. I'm confused about the inclusion of 聞く. I'm sure the act of **asking** whether or not you've memorised the word isn't the problem.

If I'd been asked to write this sentence I'd have replaced 聞く with either:

1) という
2) が
3) nothing

Would any of these options lead to a grammatical, natural sentence? Would my sentence have a different meaning?

Comment: 「覚えているかどうかを**確かめる/確認する**問題(≂質問/問い/questions)」とか。。。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

問題 here is not a “problem” in the meaning of a “general issue”, but a problem as an “exercise”, a “test item”.

Thus ことばを覚えているかどうか聞く問題 are exercises **asking** (verifying) if examinees remembered words.

And it’s not the problem itself that needs to be reduced, but the number of such problems (exercises) in exams.

---

That said, I’m not sure if the latter part of the question still remains relevant, but:

> I'd have replaced 聞く with either:
>
> 1) という

This would refer to a direct question: “did you remember the word ...?”

> 2) が

Ungrammatical. I’m not even sure what the intention was. A possessive が? Anyway, it doesn’t follow an embedded question.

> 3) nothing

Passable, I guess. No change in meaning.

Comment: `3) nothing -- Passable, I guess.` ← 「ことばを覚えているかどうか問題を減らす...」でもいい、って意味ですかね・・？

Comment: @Chocolate “I guess” means I’m not sure,  but would’t 「〜かどうか、問題〜」 work in a spoken language?

Comment: I thought an embedded question can act like a noun phrase, so が could follow it. e.g. ことばを覚えているかどうかが問題だ "the question is will I have memorised the word". In this case though, I was being a moron because that would make the question the subject of 減らす which is nonsense.

Comment: @macraf カジュアルな話し言葉では、「覚えてるか(どうか) **って**問題」とか「覚えてるか(どうか) **っていう**問題」とか言うかなと思います。「覚えてるかどうか**の**問題」とも言うかも？　カジュアルじゃなかったら、「覚えているか(どうか)(を)問う問題」とか・・